# Make a full complex search in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, search, search-engine

I am trying to make a full complex search using php and mysql.I want to use this search system for search a city in database.
For example if anyone want to search "Houston" and he entered wrong spelling, like "Hoston" instead of "Houston", the city origional city "Houston" will popup in search.
Please give me any suggestion how can I solve this and how can I make a full complex search with php and mysql.

Comment: I wouldn't use php/mysql for this. I'd use something built from the ground up for searching, like lucene (or solr on top). http://lucene.apache.org/core/, http://lucene.apache.org/solr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try  [Sphinx search engine](http://sphinxsearch.com/)  for that. It make index and keep in memory so search is very fast

Answer (score 0):

it's better to use auto complete of j query in this particular system 
 
Try this link
http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/autocomplete.htm